# How to call php function from another file?

Tags: php

I want to call my custom php function from my index.php, but the function is located in another file. Ho to do that ?

Example :

index.php :

```
<?php

myCustomFunction();

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php

function myCustomFunction(){
//some codes
}

?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change index.php as follows:

```
<?php
  include "function.php";
  myCustomFunction();
?>
```

(this is based on the assumption that both files are in the same directory, otherwise you have to add the filepath in the `include` line)

Answer (score 6):

You just need to `include` the other file:

```
include('function.php');
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php

include('function.php');

myCustomFunction();
```

The `include` function in PHP inserts in-place the code contained in the file passed to its parameter.

For further details, and alternative, please refer to PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php